# .bashrc reports unexpected EOF

Tags: bash, syntax

I am trying to add some functions to my bashrc, namely:

```
h () { history | fgrep $1 | sort -u | cut -b 8- }

extract () {
  if [ -f $1 ] ; then
      case $1 in
          *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf $1    ;;
          *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf $1    ;;
          *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1     ;;
          *.rar)       rar e $1       ;;
          *.gz)        gunzip $1      ;;
          *.tar)       tar xvf $1     ;;
          *.tbz2)      tar xvjf $1    ;;
          *.tgz)       tar xvzf $1    ;;
          *.zip)       unzip $1       ;;
          *.Z)         uncompress $1  ;;
          *.7z)        7z x $1        ;;
          *)           echo "I don't know how to extract '$1'." ;;
      esac
  else
      echo "'$1' is not a valid file!"
  fi
}
```

using the following command:

```
echo -e "\
h () { history | fgrep \044\061 | sort -u | cut -b 8- }  

extract () {
  if [ -f \044\061 ] ; then
      case \044\061 in
          *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf \044\061    ;;
          *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf \044\061    ;;
          *.bz2)       bunzip2 \044\061     ;;
          *.rar)       rar e \044\061       ;;
          *.gz)        gunzip \044\061      ;;
          *.tar)       tar xvf \044\061     ;;
          *.tbz2)      tar xvjf \044\061    ;;
          *.tgz)       tar xvzf \044\061    ;;
          *.zip)       unzip \044\061       ;;
          *.Z)         uncompress \044\061  ;;
          *.7z)        7z x \044\061        ;;
          *)           echo \042I don't know how to extract '\044\061'.\042 ;;
      esac
  else
      echo \042'\044\061' is not a valid file\041\042
  fi
}" >> ~/.bashrc
```

...but this results in `bash: /home/chris/.bashrc: line 123: syntax error: unexpected end of file` when bash starts up. If I remove these functions, this error goes away. Is there some closing statement I must add to the functions section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line is the problem.

```
h () { history | fgrep $1 | sort -u | cut -b 8- }
```

Change it to this:

```
h () { history | fgrep $1 | sort -u | cut -b 8- ; }
```

Or:

```
h () {
    history | fgrep $1 | sort -u | cut -b 8-
}
```

Also, an easier/cleaner way to get it into your `.bashrc` is with redirection (although you do still need to escape `$`).

```
cat >> .bashrc << EOF
h () { history | fgrep \$1 | sort -u | cut -b 8- ; }

extract () {
  if [ -f \$1 ] ; then
      case \$1 in
          *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf \$1    ;;
          *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf \$1    ;;
          *.bz2)       bunzip2 \$1     ;;
          *.rar)       rar e \$1       ;;
          *.gz)        gunzip \$1      ;;
          *.tar)       tar xvf \$1     ;;
          *.tbz2)      tar xvjf \$1    ;;
          *.tgz)       tar xvzf \$1    ;;
          *.zip)       unzip \$1       ;;
          *.Z)         uncompress \$1  ;;
          *.7z)        7z x \$1        ;;
          *)           echo "I don't know how to extract '\$1'." ;;
      esac
  else
      echo "'\$1' is not a valid file!"
  fi
}
EOF
```

Comment: +1 That's right, there's no need to do all that octal escaping if you do it this way. But you could do `\$1` which would be more readable than `\044\061`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Why not just use `nano` or some other editor vs redirection?

Comment: @Just Jake: Perhaps this needs to be deployed repeatedly, possibly for multiple accounts or on multiple machines. Doing it with a script automates it. However, it should probably be more robust, for example checking that it hasn't already been done. It's possible the OP is doing that and we just don't see that part.

Comment: It does need to be automated, indeed. I'll test this in a few minutes (off for dinner now). Thanks! :)

Comment: Hm, `$1` still seems to need escaping, or it gets interpreted (how should I even escape it when it gets redirected?). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't notice that when I tried it earlier. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: `\$1` still doesn't seem to work, which was my confusion (tried that before posting my reply), it keeps the \ and continues to interpret `$1`

Comment: Are you using `cat >> .bashrc << EOF`? It works for me. If you are trying to use `echo` you need to use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: Yup, I'm using the exact method you've posted. OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Bump, any ideas? :)

Comment: I have no idea. It works for me. I've tried everything I can think of to do it wrong and I can't break it. I tried pasting it, putting it in a script with each of `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/zsh` and everything works for me. What version of bash are you using? Run `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION` returns `4.1.5(1)-release`.

Comment: In the end I've just `cat`'ed in a file. Thanks anyway, but since this seems to work for some, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your shebang to

> #!/bin/bash -x

and run the program again, to get a line by line trace. Usually unexpected end of file is an unclosed quote or bracket.

Comment: The shebang seems to do nothing (but isn't that expected since this is .bashrc?)

Comment: Just tried running it with `./.bashrc`... I see nothing of use other than at the end `./.bashrc: line 124: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. What should I be looking for?